# Getting client ip address on WCF CustomUserNameValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, c#-4.0

We are using CustomUserNameValidator on our WCF project. I need to get client ip adresses when I'm authenticating.  OperationContext is null, I cannot get it. ı don't want to turn on Asp.Net Compability mode on.

```
 public class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        if (null == userName || null == password)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        try
        {
            int userId = Common.AuthenticateUser(userName, password); //need ip adresses here
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenException("Unauthorized");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any resolve about this issue?

Comment: You need to understand why operationcontext is null. Are you calling the web service from a client or are you unit testing the method ?

Comment: operationcontext is null because it is not created. It must pass validation step for get value.

Comment: Then only option is to use extensibility features. check https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/04/04/wcf-extensibility-iendpointbehavior/ and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/03/14/wcf-extensibility/